# Embed a html screen into Html table cell shrinking html to fit to cell size

Tags: html, html-table, cell

How can I insert a html page into a HTML table cell and make the HTML fit the cell so that no scroll bar exists and i can see the entire page without scrolling within the cell?

Currently I have but the cell always has a scroll bar on it so I can't see entire page.

```
<table class="styleTbl">
    <tr class="styleRow">
        <td class="styleObj">
            <object data=index.html height="100%" width="100%"></object></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use iframe with `scrolling="no"` attributes.

Of course, adjust `width`, `height`, `src`, `frameborder` as needed.

```
<iframe src="http://www.google.com" width="50%" height="50%" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```